# cp -a cannot overwrite symlinked directory

Tags: macos, bash, symlink

I have a folder that contains symlinked folders.

```
root
 |- Current document -> version 2 document
 |- Current folder -> version 2 folder
 |- Archives
     |- version 1 document
     |- version 1 folder
         |- ...
     |- version 2 document
     |- version 2 folder
         |- ...
```

When I copy this directory with `cp -r`, the folder copies, but since `-r` follows symlinks, version 2 is copied twice.

When I copy this directory with `cp -R`, the folder copies fine the first time and preserves the symlinks. However, on the second copy, it is unable to overwrite the folder, stating:

```
cp: cannot overwrite directory 'Current folder' with 'Current folder'
```

I also tried `cp -a` == `cp -pPR` as well as the `-f` versions (`cp -fR` and `cp -fa`)

I think it's tests to see if `Current Folder` is a folder by following symlinks and then fails to overwrite the symlink (which it thinks it's a folder) with a symlink.

What's the right command to consistently copy and overwrite a folder with symlinked folders?

Comment: Something I don't understand. If the first time preserves the symlink, why you need an overwrite ? If you look into the copied-symlinked folder, don't you see the updated files in there... ?

Comment: I'll update with a new version, say Version 3, and then need to point the symlinks at the new version.

Comment: Another thing that I don't understand is that going into the finder and copy and pasting is the right behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[On OSX, use `ditto`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html)

It has the same behavior as osx copy/paste.

---

P.S.
One gotcha that you might want to watch out for:

```
cp -a foo bar
```

will move the folder foo/ into bar/ (ie bar/foo/file1, bar/foo/file2)

```
ditto foo bar
```

will move the **contents** of folder foo/ into bar (ie bar/file1, bar/file2)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly the answer, but may help understand what exactly that you are looking for. Here is what I get :

```
# Assume all these happening in a parent directory name pdir.

mkdir -p test/s
mkdir -p test1/s1
cd test/s
ln -s ../../test1/s1 .  # created a symlink

# go to parent dir pdir

mkdir -p test2
cp -R test/* test2/     # Now I copy all the content of test to test2. test contains a symlink directory

ls -ld test2/s/*
18 Aug 21 14:53 test2/s/s1@ -> ../../test1/s1  # symlink dir is preserved during the copy

# Now I want to modify my source directory before copying again
# This time I will modify inside the source directory which I have already symlinked

touch test1/s1/test.txt

# Without copying I check that the symlink is correctly updated, I don't even need a copy anymore

ls -ld test2/s/s1/*
0 Aug 21 14:55 test2/s/s1/test.txt


# Now I want to create a symlink inside the source symlink directory
cd test1/
touch tmp1.txt
cd s1/
ln -s ../tmp1.txt .  # Here it is created

# go back to parent dir pdir
# Do the same copy again

cp -R test/* test2/  

# You will receive this error:  
cp: cannot overwrite directory test2/stest/stest1 with non-directory test/stest/stest1
#of course it can't because it is already there
# even though it complains it can't overwrite the symlink of the dir, 
# but it correctly updates the files that are recently created inside the source dir

ls -ld test2/s/s1/*
 0 Aug 21 14:55 test2/s/s1/test.txt
 10 Aug 21 14:59 test2/s/s1/tmp1.txt@ -> ../tmp1.txt
```

Hope it helps...